# Why get There is no handle /play when try to access localhost:8123/play [ClickHouse]?

Tags: clickhouse

when I try to access the localhost:8123/play I get the following message:

There is no handle /play

Use / or /ping for health checks.
Or /replicas_status for more sophisticated health checks.

Send queries from your program with POST method or GET /?query=...

Use clickhouse-client:

For interactive data analysis:
clickhouse-client

For batch query processing:
clickhouse-client --query='SELECT 1' > result
clickhouse-client < query > result

what should i do?

Comment: How did you install clickhouse? And how do you run the server? See a quick tutorial here: https://clickhouse.com/learn/lessons/gettingstarted/

Comment: I'm using 20.7.4.11 but It was added in v20.11.2.1, 2020-11-11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was added in v20.11.2.1, 2020-11-11